# Remove blank lines that appear when writing to file (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, file, println

I have created a program which takes a text file full of 3 letter words and processes them, stores them in an array and then outputs to the build output in JCreator and then writes the same output to a file.

Now, this program works fine, but when I print a lot of data - I get all of these blank lines inserted where there shouldn't be any.

I use this to print to my file:

```
PrintWriter fw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("Dictionary.txt")); 

   for (int i=0; i<count; i++)
   {
       if (words[i]!=null)
           fw.println(words[i]);
   }
```

I loop through the array and don't print to a file, just to my output screen on the IDE. Now, I will suddenly get a blank line where there shouldn't be, like so:

> tut
>   tux
>
> uke
>   use

and it seems to be completely random.

Now how would I remove these lines from the file without having to write to a new file, as writing large amounts of lines seems to cause this problem.

Thanks guys

Comment: Maybe some of the words are actually empty? Have you checked if `words[i].length() == 0`?

Comment: Another thread is printing something else?

Comment: The words weren't empty, as I was printing an array, the empty values would have just printed "null" on the line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a small change:

```
if (words[i]!=null && words[i].trim().length() != 0)
       fw.println(words[i]);
```

Basically, you want to check and see if the line would be blank, and skip printing it.

Comment: Removing the empty lines from the dictionary seems like a good move indeed :)

Comment: I thought so too, but it's random so it doesn't seem to be that.

Comment: @Colin, my guess is that it isn't actually random.

Comment: Hi Justin, it worked. The blank lines have been removed. Thank you. BTW, it's .length(), my IDE spat that at me...

Comment: @Justin: No worries, this has helped a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

**If it's totally random**, then you should try to write in a file and check this file. Not that I don't trust the console provided by your IDE.

Comment: I wrote to the file, and the output to the console and the file are exactly the same.